# Omiting relative pronouns

Tags: relative-pronouns, relative-clauses, past-participles, present-participles

I've been confused with the relative pronouns. I bring the following examples and the result after removing relative pronouns? Are they correct?

> 1a. This is the window **which** has been broken by me. ==>
>   1b. This is the window has been broken by me. (present perfect passive)
>
> 2a. This is the window **which** will be broken by me. ==>
>   2b. This is the window will be broken by me. (future passive)
>
> 3a. This is the window **which is** broken by me. ==>
>   3b. This is the window broken by me. (present passive)
>
> 4a. This is the window **which** was broken by me. ==>
>   4b. This is the window was broken by me. (past passive)
>
> 5a. This is Peter **who** will be playing football tomorrow. ==>
>   5b. This is Peter will be playing football tomorrow. (future continuous)
>
> 6a. This is Peter **who** was playing football yesterday. ==>
>   6b. This is Peter was playing football yesterday. (past continuous)
>
> 7a. This is Peter **who is** playing football now. ==>
>   7b. This is Peter playing football now. (present continuous)

Comment: Are you proposing to take out just the relative pronoun, or remove everything within parentheses?  You have to preserve the tense of the verbs. And the verbs don't mean anything without the relative pronoun. Only in 1  & 3 could you omit the words in parenteses, but then they would be identical.

Comment: I edited the post for more clarification.

Comment: Much clearer now. They're all wrong. No, you cannot remove the relative pronoun.

Comment: All wrong?!! Even in 3 and 7? I don't know why but It sounds correct at least for these two.

Comment: My bad. 3 is ok. 7 is grammatical, but I think it carries a subtly different meaning. Maybe so subtle as to be a decent substitution.

Answer (score 1):

If the sentence structure of your examples is to be kept, a relative pronoun is required in 1. and 2. but not in 3. "This is the window broken by me," is acceptable English. You *could* change the structure of 1. and 2. slightly to omit a pronoun, e.g. "This window has been broken by me," and "This window will be broken by me," but that omits "is a" in each case.

The same is true for 5. and 6. The meaning is approximately the same, but you need to omit "is a" if you omit "who".