# Do Americans usually omit relative pronoun in oral English?

Tags: subordinate-clauses, ellipsis

I learnt from [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/47593/10484) that the relative pronoun cannot be omitted in the following sentence:

> I have a lived experience and I think one of the challenges with
>   regards to mental illness compared to physical injuries, is physical
>   injuries are easy to digest.

But in [this episode](http://www.abc.net.au/tv/qanda/txt/s4303400.htm) of the Australia talk show QandA, an AFL player Wayne Schwass used this pattern several times. I just wonder if this is allowed and normal in daily life.

> ...because what I will say is what you've done is someone in that
>   auditorium or hall is having the same challenges that they’re facing
>   and your story has connected with them and they’ve probably got some
>   inspiration out of what you’ve done,...

Comment: I can't see a relative pronoun in your first sentence.

Comment: It is helpful if you highlight the word(s) in question in you examples.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your first sentence, and it doesn't seem to be addressed by the answer you link to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect what you're asking about is this omission:

> I think one of the challenges with regards to mental illness compared to physical injuries, is **<s>that</s>** physical injuries are easy to digest.

But in this case *that* is not a *relative pronoun*; it's called a *subordinating conjunction* in traditional grammar or a *subordinator* or *complementizer* in more recent grammars.

- Relative *that* signals the presence of a 'gap' (a missing constituent) in the following clause and "relates" that gap to a constituent in the head clause.
- Complementizer *that* signals that the following full clause is to be treated as a nominal constituent in the main clause—as it does in this very sentence.

Omission of complementizer *that* is very frequent in speech, both British and American, and this is often acceptable in written English, too. However, I advise against omitting it in writing unless your sentence structure is simple: it helps the reader sort out how your sentence is put together.